# Can I use CHAR_BIT as the basis for determining the number of bits in other types?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

For example, does the following code make no assumptions that might be incorrect on certain systems?

```
 // Number of bits in an unsigned long long int:
 const int ULLONG_BIT = sizeof(unsigned long long int) * CHAR_BIT;
```

Comment: Theoretically, some of those bits might be padding bits.

Comment: For which purpose? Storage or calculations?

Comment: Calculation - the problem that prompted me to post this question was counting 1 bits in an int for parity.

Comment: Well, I guess as @PSkocik have noted, it won't be *absolutely* portable in terms of calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with PSkocik's comment to the original question. C11 6.2.6 says `CHAR_BIT * sizeof (type)` yields the number of bits in the *object representation* of type `type`, but some of them may be padding bits.

I *suspect* that your best bet for a "no-assumptions" code is to simply check the value of `ULLONG_MAX` (or `~0ULL` or `(unsigned long long)(-1LL)`, which should all evaluate to the same value):

```
#include <limits.h>

static inline int ullong_bit(void)
{
    unsigned long long m = ULLONG_MAX;
    int n = 0, i = 0;
    while (m) {
        n += m & 1;
        i ++;
        m >>= 1;
    }
    if (n == i)
        return i;
    else
        return i-1;
}
```

If the binary pattern for the value is all ones, then the number of bits an `unsigned long long` can hold is the same as the number of binary digits in the value.

Otherwise, the most significant bit cannot really be used, because the maximum value in binary contains zeros.